# How to get 3 float numbers randomly with the step of 0.5 between 5.0 and 9.0 using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How to get 3 float numbers randomly with the step of 0.5 between 5.0 and 9.0 using Numpy?

I tried as follows:

```
np.random.uniform(5.0,9.0)
```

But it does not include the 'step' parameter.

EDIT:
Python random.randrange provides the way of using 'step'. But it works only for integers.

```
random.randrange(start, stop[, step])
```

I want to get 3 such numbers:

The expected result should be as follows:

```
ans = [5.5, 6.0, 8.5]
```

Comment: Writers must explain what they mean by "step" in this context.

Comment: ?  Putting something in bold doesn't explain it.  It's clear you want `step` to be 0.5; it's not clear what `step` *is*.  Do you mean that you want the only returned values to be `5.0, 5.5, 6.0, ..., 9.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use something like @ebarr's answer, but here's an alternative.

Create the desired range using `np.arange`, and then select from that array using `np.random.choice`:

```
In [134]: np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 9, 0.5), size=3)
Out[134]: array([ 7. ,  8.5,  7.5])
```

Note that if you use `arange` like this, `9` is not included in the possible output.  If you want to include the upper limit, you could use `np.arange(5, 9.25, 0.5)`, or more generally, `np.arange(start, stop+0.5*step, step)`.

This is not very efficient if the desired range is large and you only select a few values.  If you are going to repeatedly select from the same set of numbers, you can define the possible values once and reuse that variable:

```
In [135]: values = np.arange(5, 9, 0.5)

In [136]: np.random.choice(values, size=3)
Out[136]: array([ 6.5,  5. ,  6. ])

In [137]: np.random.choice(values, size=5)
Out[137]: array([ 6. ,  8. ,  6. ,  7.5,  8. ])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just divide...

```
val = np.random.randint(2*5,2*9)/2.
```

`randint` returns a uniformly distributed integer in the range [10,18) and then you just do a float division by 2. This has the benefit of being fairly fast:

```
In [120]: %timeit np.random.randint(2*5,2*9)/2.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 329 ns per loop

In [121]: %timeit 0.5 * ceil(2.0 * np.random.uniform(5.0, 9.0))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.61 µs per loop
```

To make this a bit more generic:

```
def rand_with_step(low,high,step,count=1,bias=False):
    n = 1/step
    if count > 1:
        val = np.random.randint(low*n,high*n,count)*step
    else:
        val= np.random.randint(low*n,high*n)*step

    if bias:
        bias = ceil(low/step)*step - low
    else:
        bias = 0
    return val - bias
```

here the bias flag determines whether the steps are counted starting at the value of `low`.

For example:

```
In [190]: rand_with_step(5,9,0.11,1,True)
Out[190]: 7.31
```

Which should be correct as ( 7.31 - 5 )/0.11 = 29 a full multiple of the step.

It's worth noting that this method is faster than `np.random.choice` even with a pre-calculated pool of numbers to draw from (although it is not clear to me why).

```
In [343]: x = np.arange(5, 9, 0.5)

In [344]: %timeit np.random.choice(x,size=3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.7 µs per loop

In [345]: %timeit rand_with_step(5,9,0.5,3,True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
0.5 * floor(2.0 * np.random.uniform(5.0, 9.0))
```

Hope that was helpful.